# Client-Server architecture

Tags: c#, client-server

This topic has been discussed million times before, but let me clarify my needs:
I need a single server which controls a system and includes the necessary functions. Furthermore, there will be "n" Clients which represents only the HI/GUI and call server side functions. The server itself should be able to send data back to the clients and call client-side functions too (like shutdown, exit and so on...)

I have heard about duplex services/contracts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), but I'm not sure how far I'll come with that.
How would you handle this?

Comment: If I understand, you are looking for a kind a centralized peer to peer, like bit-torrent?

Comment: Kind of, but the clients don't need to communicate by each other. I need only Client-Server and Server-Client communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently made a proof of concept app that made both the server and the client host a WCF service each. The client connects to the server and then in a handshake call, gives the server the connection information to allow the server create a separate connection back to the client. It worked a treat with multiple clients on network links from local lan to 64k line on remote sites at the same time.

Comment: this sounds quite interesting. Did you use an IIS server to host the service side WCF service? I wasn't specific enough, it would be great if we wouldn't need any IIS server.

Comment: You don't need IIS, you can host a wcf service in a console app, win app, a win service or IIS. The benefit I found was that you basically can have two way comms regardless of the binding you use. HTTP or tcp. The client does not need to poll the server for updates, its WCF host just listens for a server call.

Comment: thank you very much. I have tried your solution, it works fine for me and satisfy my needs. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use WCF, and host the service on the server in IIS, in the application on the client and let the client register it's endpoint on the server.